# Закрытие диалога своей кнопкой

Tags: java, android, dialog

У меня есть свой кастомный диалог с кнопкой "Применить". Когда пользователь нажимает на эту кнопку диалог должен закрыться. Т.к. я использую View.onClickListener, я не получаю DialogInterface, который могу использовать для закрытия диалога. Мб кто знает, как это сделать? Вот мой код:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Body.this);
final View inflate = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialog_color, 
null);
dialog.setView(inflate);
dialog.show();
Button apply = inflate.findViewById(R.id.applyColor);
apply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
          //тут собираюсь закрыть диалоговое окно.
     }
});
```

Comment: dialog.dismiss();

Comment: @Style-7 Было бы всё так просто, я б не спрашивал. Я использую свою кнопку и другой метод(View.onClickListener вместо DialogInterface.onClickListener) первый не предоставляет DialogInterface, который обычно используют вместе с dismiss() или cancel().

Comment: И что? В чем проблема через dialog закрыть. И зачем использовать в диалоге другие кнопки, если есть встроенные по стандарту поведения.

Comment: @Style-7 Свои кнопки использую, т.к. придерживаюсь стилю приложения, а dialog.dismiss(); или dialog.cancel(); не работают. (Cannot resolve method 'dismiss').

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось выйти из ситуации. Нужно было подкорректировать эту строку:

```
dialog.show();
```

Так:

```
final AlertDialog ad = dialog.show();
```

и потом использовать ad.dismiss(); Как я понял, AlertDialog.Builder не имеет метода dismiss(); и cancel();

Comment: Всё верно. AlertDialog.Builder - это реализация шаблона/паттерна "Строитель", и создана исключительно для конструирования объекта AlertDialog и имеет только соответствующие методы. Обычно, для получения итогового объекта из объекта строителя используют методы с названием `build()`. В данном случае метод называется или `show()`, или вызывается внутри метода `show()`